# Using multiple OR conditions in ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I've a column of names

Smith John Sr
Smith John R
Smith Jr John L
Smith III John
Smith John IV

I know the Last Name is always the first word.
I know the First is sometimes in the second word.
However, sometimes "Jr" or "III" may be there instead.
Otherwise, the title can be in the fourth word if it is not the middle initial.

How do I use an arrayformula with multiple OR conditions so that I can extract into a second column the First Name, The Last Name, and the Applicable Title (e.g. Jr, Sr, III, IV). I want to disregard the initial which I figured I could use a character count "=1" within the OR logic, correct?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your working formula, you can use +  to join conditions that are meant to be at least one of them met (like OR) and * to join conditions that are meant to be together (like AND). For example:

```
=IF(OR(A1=1,B1=1),1,0)
```

As an array you could do it:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((A1:A=1)+(B1:B=1),TRUE,FALSE))
```

Since TRUE conditions are considered as 1 and FALSE conditions as 0, when you sum two conditions it will return 1 or more if one of them is TRUE; and with that positive result, it will apply the true statement of the IF. Hope it's useful

Comment: Hi - I made this sheet to help better figure this out. I added the following questions to the sheet. Thank you for your help; I'm a student trying to learn. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F9tuDleDn4dqg0WEkChl6dMChgWRs-KAPzQJE09tAJM/edit?usp=sharing